# In Magento 2, Set base image as small image

Tags: magento2, product-images

I have nearly 40k products and all images have been set to small only. If I go into the backend and then set each image one by one to the base, it will take me forever. Is there any way to do it via the database?

Comment: You want to set small image which is already set in base image?

Comment: I want to set a base image which is already set in the small image.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to do by MySQL way follow below way

First, run below query to know the query is actually working and you will get a list of images

```
select  ev.value, mg.value from catalog_product_entity_media_gallery AS mg,
catalog_product_entity_media_gallery_value AS mgv,
catalog_product_entity_varchar AS ev
WHERE  mg.value_id = mgv.value_id
AND mgv.entity_id = ev.entity_id
AND ev.attribute_id IN (87, 88, 89)
AND mgv.position = 1;
```

After that run below query to update small image path with a thumbnail image

```
UPDATE catalog_product_entity_media_gallery AS mg,
catalog_product_entity_media_gallery_value AS mgv,
catalog_product_entity_varchar AS ev
SET ev.value = mg.value
WHERE  mg.value_id = mgv.value_id
AND mgv.entity_id = ev.entity_id
AND ev.attribute_id IN (87, 88, 89)
AND mgv.position = 1;
```

You should run first in test ENV, after making sure you can run on other ENV.

Hope It will solve your issue

Answer (score 0):

You can use the CSV.
Please add two more column 'base_image' and 'thumbnail_image' in the csv file and re import all the products.Then after reindex the process.

Comment: Image Url does not generate  When I import via CSV file.I have done this

Answer (score 0):

It does possible with the csv import too.

1. Get the attribute ids.

Go to admin > stores > attributes > product and search image attributes there. Lets say your image attribute id is 79 , small image is 80 and thumbnail id is 81.

2. In this case, small image attribute id is 80 so run this query.

SELECT `attribute_id`,`store_id`,`entity_id`,`value` FROM `catalog_product_entity_varchar` WHERE `attribute_id`=80

3. Export the query result and change the id from 80 to 79 ( 79 is the attribute id of image).
4. Import the updated csv in database.
5. Repeat the same step for thumbnail.